# IndexError: list index out of range при использовании дистанции Левенштейна

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Я не нашёл решения своей проблемы на просторах интернета, и я решил задать вопрос в обитель знаний и помощи программистам StackOverFlow.
При проверке переменных current_row[j], возникают ошибки №1,№2 и №3:

1. Ошибка возникает при проверке слова длинною меньше чем distance, а также если хоть 1 буква не совпадает с b (или же нужного слова).
2. Ошибка возникает при проверке слова длинною больше чем distance, а также если хоть 1 буква не совпадает с b (или же нужного слова).
3. Ошибка возникает если есть буквы, которых нет в b (distance или же нужное слово).

Попытка использования try + except не сильно помогла в решении проблемы, ведь нужного результата я не получил.
Если вопрос составлен неправильно, то укажите на ошибки исправлю и обещаю больше их допускать не буду.

```
            for c in chars:
                if c in event.text:
                    event.text = event.text.replace(c, "")  
            for symbol in symbols:
                if symbol in event.text.lower():
                    event.text = event.text.lower().replace(symbol, syllables[symbols.index(symbol)])
            a = event.text.lower()
            b = "Привет"
            n, m = len(a), len(b)
            if n > m:
                a, b = b, a
                n, m = m, n
            current_row = range(n+1)
            for i in range(1, m+1):
                previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i]+[0]*n
                for j in range(1,n+1):
                    add, delete, change = previous_row[j]+1, current_row[j-1]+1, previous_row[j-1]
                    if a[j-1] != b[i-1]:
                        change += 1
                    current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)
            message = "Прости, не понимаю тебя."
            distance = len(a)
            a1 = 0
            d1 = 0
            c1 = 0
            if current_row[add] != distance + 1:
                if current_row[add] <= distance + 1:
                    a1 = 1
                elif current_row[add] > distance + 1:
                    a1 = 2
            if current_row[delete] != distance:
                if current_row[delete] <= distance:
                    d1 = 1
                elif current_row[delete] > distance:
                    d1 = 2
            if current_row[change] != distance + 1:
                if current_row[change] <= distance:
                    c1 = 1
                elif current_row[change] > distance:
                    c1 = 2
            if a1 == 1 and d1 == 1 and c1 == 0 or a1 == 1 and d1 == 1 and c1 == 1 or a1 == 0 and d1 == 1 and c1 == 0: # И так далее, после решения проблемы с переменными допишу остальные варианты "правильного слова"
                message = 'Я понял ваш запрос как "%s"\n\n' % 'Привет' + message
                print(message, end='')
                print(str(a1),str(d1),str(c1))
                break
            else:
                print(message, end='')
                print(str(a1),str(d1),str(c1))
                break
```

Comment: Не хватает в вашем вопросе минимального кода для воспроизведения ошибки. Кст, а попробуйте эти примеры (там посторонние модули): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/7bb1dd03623505c47696a8af38a1c69430878b47/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @gil9red , спасибо за помощь. Можно считать вопрос закрытым.